# Kinesis Data Firehose and Glue Race conditions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-firehose

We are using Kinesis Data Firehose to write RDS CDC data to S3 buckets as raw json files.  Our Kinesis Firehose configuration is 128 MB and 60 seconds to create the S3 files. We have a glue job that monitors the s3 buckets and picks up these json file. We have a question on whether we will run into a race condition between a json file that is being currently written by  Kinesis Firehose and Glue. I looked at the FAQ, but I could not get any pointers. Please let me know if the race condition is possible and any strategies that can mitigate this condition
https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/faqs/

Answer (score 0):

If you worry that your glue job will start working with a partially written file by Kinesis, then you should know that S3 operations are **atomic** as exampled in [Amazon S3 data consistency model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html):

> Updates to a single key are **atomic**. For example, if you PUT to an existing key, a subsequent read might return the old data or the updated data, but it **never returns corrupted or partial data**.